# Adding list of overlapping polygons to attributes of unique polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features, batch

I have two vector layers each made up of around 1000 unique polygons. Is there a way to add to the attributes of each polygon in Layer 1 a list of the polygons it overlaps in Layer 2? Can this be batched?

I'm working in QGIS on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ["Field Calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with an expression like this:

```
array_to_string(
    array:=overlay_intersects(
            layer:='counties',
            expression:=kom_kod
            ),
    delimiter:=', '
)
```

[image]